# Console error, even if everything is working?

Tags: themes, errors

I get this error in my console when visiting the admin pages:

```
GET https://example/test/wp-content/plugins/home/account/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme-theme/inc/custom-script.js?ver=4.9.4 net::ERR_ABORTED
```

I have tracked down the error to the code below:

```
function theme_add_color_picker( $hook ) {

if( is_admin() ) {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script-handle', plugins_url( 'custom-script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-color-picker', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/admin/admin-color-picker.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

}
}
```

The problem here is that custom-script.js isn't available inside the /inc folder, and it is nowhere in the theme-folder at all.
But the color picker works perfectly. And if I remove this line:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script-handle', plugins_url( 'custom-script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );
```

It will stop working all together.
So how come I get this error, but it still works?

Would like to have a clean console log.

EDIT:

I changed to this instead:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' );
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).wpColorPicker is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (admin-color-picker.js?ver=4.9.4:3)
at i (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,thickbox&ver=4.9.4:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,thickbox&ver=4.9.4:2)
at Function.ready (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,thickbox&ver=4.9.4:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,thickbox&ver=4.9.4:2)
```

Comment: What happens if you just enqueue `'wp-color-picker'` instead?

Comment: I thought that solved it. Changed to wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' ); 
Now I get another error instead. Updated main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colour picker is working fine because it's a separate script being enqueued as a dependency of `custom-script-handle`. So even if `custom-script-handle` isn't loading because the URL is wrong the colour picker script will still load.

If you don't enqueue `custom-script-handle` then the colour picker won't work because the script is being enqueued at all. You would need to enqueue it separately with `wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' );`

The reason `custom-script-handle` itself isn't loading, and causing the console error that you see, is because the URL is wrong. The reason the URL is wrong is because you're using `plugins_url()` incorrectly. Specifically in how you've used `__FILE__`.

From [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/), the 2nd argument to `plugins_url()` is:

> A full path to a file inside a plugin or mu-plugin. The URL will be
>   relative to its directory. Typically this is done by passing `__FILE__`
>   as the argument.

The problem is that in your case `__FILE__` is within a theme. So your `__FILE__` is:

```
/home/account/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme-theme/inc/{whatever-the-file-name-is}.php
```

But the plugins directory is:

```
/home/account/public_html/wp-content/plugins
```

WordPress already knows the URL to the plugins folder, `https://example/test/wp-content/plugins/`, but needs to use those two paths to figure out the URL to the specific file you've requested. So what `plugins_url()` does is try to figure out the plugin folder by subtracting that second path from the first path.

So if used *correctly*, `__FILE__` will be something like:

```
/home/account/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/inc/assets.php
```

The plugin path is then subtracted from this and you get:

```
my-plugin/inc/assets.php
```

`plugins_url()` then takes off the filename:

```
my-plugin/inc
```

Then adds the filename you provided in the first argument (`custom-script.js`):

```
/my-plugin/inc/custom-script.js
```

And finally adds that to the plugins *URL*:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/inc/custom-script.js
```

But since your `__FILE__` isn't in the plugins folder, there's no overlap. So when it subtracts the plugin directory and filename the relative path is still:

```
/home/account/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme-theme/inc/
```

And then that and the filename get added to the plugins URL and you end up with this:

```
https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/home/account/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme-theme/inc/custom-script.js
```

So if you need your theme to enqueue `custom-script.js`, you either need to put it in the theme or enqueue it using the handle the plugin will have already registered for it. Don't try an load files from a plugin directly from within a theme.